# Is there a way to auto map complicated raw queries to entity models?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, orm, entity-framework-core, asp.net-core-2.2

I have an application that is written using `C#` on the top of ASP.NET Core 2.2 Framework. The application uses Entity Framework Core as an ORM to interact with the database.

Entity Framework has been good to me in many cases. It is extremely helpful in simple CRUD, or even when add/update/delete a small amount of data.

However, when I need to read somewhat large dataset or data generated by a complex query it is too slow. In many cases I find Entity Framework over complicate queries which cause my app to slow down. I guess this the disadvantage of using ORM. But an ORM is must have in my case!

With that in mind, I am looking for a solution where I can keep using ORM in most cases but find a way to pull data using custom query and directly map the same query to the entity models. I can directly use ADO.NET to execute raw queries that I write which gives me high performance. But, I need a way to auto map the requests to entity models.

For the sake of explaining what I am looking for, assume the following query Entity Frameworks over complicates and I found a better query to get the same data. Here is my better raw query

```
SELECT u.username, u.firstname, u.lastname, p.*
FROM users AS u
INNER JOIN (
   SELECT id, title, description, userid
   FROM posts
   WHERE deletedon IS NULL AND publishedon BETWEEN '2019-07-01' AND '2019-07-10'
) AS p
WHERE u.deletedon IS NULL
```

I have the following entity model

```
public class User 
{
  public int id { get ; set; }
  public string username { get ; set; }
  public string firstname { get ; set; }
  public string lastname { get ; set; }
  public DateTime deletedon { get ; set; }

  public virtual ICollection<Post> posts { get ; set; }
}

public class Post 
{
  public int id { get ; set; }
  public string title{ get ; set; }
  public string description { get ; set; }
  public int userId { get ; set; }
  public DateTime deletedon { get ; set; }
  public DateTime publishedon { get ; set; }

  public virtual User user { get ; set; }
}
```

Is there a tool that could take either a query or a data-table object and map it to my `User` object?

Answer (score 1):

The short answer is - no (currently).

It's listed in [Raw SQL Queries - Limitations](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/raw-sql#limitations):

> - The SQL query cannot contain related data.

I believe this is because EF Core in general does not use single SQL query for retrieving correlated collection data, but one query for the main data and one query for each related collection, i.e. for the sample model it will use 2 SQL queries.

You can still use raw SQL queries to return sets of some flattened [query type](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/query-types), but then you have to populate entity models manually (or with help of 3rd party libraries like AutoMapper).

Answer (score 0):

You can save the query as a stored procedure and bring it to the model.edmx.